# Creating multiple comboboxes from one list and receiving the result of each?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

This is my first post, so I am not completely sure how this works. The ultimate vision for this program is to create a GUI using Python Tkinter to plan a Michigan Road Trip. The tricky part of the code is having multiple frames for asking multiple questions. My first is a check button list of cities they can choose to visit; the ones they choose are then plotted on a canvas and stored in a list selected_cities. The continue_1 button then brings them to a second frame, where I am currently having issues.

I would like to create comboboxes from the list of selected_cities, where they can choose the order they would like to travel in, starting with City #1, etc. However, I am having trouble being able to store each choice, especially since I am using a for loop. Currently, my program returns Py_Var# for each selection. How can I make it so that the actual values are returned, not something else? I don't know whether to use .get() or .append() or something else. Also, do I have to bind a combobox selection to the command to add the value, as I have done?

Also, I know this has been asked elsewhere, but maybe not in this context. Is there a way of deleting the cities from the other comboboxes after they have been selected. Any help you can give me would be great! It has been a struggle.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MichiganRoadTrip:
    '''MichiganRoadTrip runs a TKinter program modeling a road trip planner and display screen based off user input.'''

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('950x750')
        picture = PhotoImage(file='michigan_map.gif')
        self.window.picture = picture

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, bg='white', width=500, height=550, highlightbackground='navy')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.create_image(250, 275, image=picture)

        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.display_coordinates)

        self.make_frame_1()

        results_frame = Frame(window)
        results_frame.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    def make_frame_1(self):
        self.frame_1 = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
        welcome_label = Label(self.frame_1, text='Hello! Welcome to the Road Trip Planner!')
        welcome_label.grid()

        self.cities = {'Holland': [257, 445], 'Grand Rapids': [281, 427], 'Ann Arbor': [396, 482],
                    'Traverse City': [291, 292], 'Lansing': [349, 452], 'Kalamazoo': [293, 486],
                    'Detroit': [430, 477],'Frankenmuth': [394, 401], 'Sault Ste. Marie': [357, 154],
                    'Sleeping Bear Dunes National Park': [265, 280]}
        self.selected = {}
        for city in self.cities:
            is_selected = BooleanVar()
            self.city_button = Checkbutton(self.frame_1, text=city, variable=is_selected)
            self.city_button.grid(sticky=W)
            self.selected[city] = is_selected

        continue1_button = Button(self.frame_1, text='Continue', command=lambda:[self.choose_cities(), self.make_frame_2(),
                                                                                 self.frame_1.destroy()])
        continue1_button.grid(sticky=N)

    def make_frame_2(self):
        self.frame_2 = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame_2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
        self.frame_2_label = Label(self.frame_2, text='Next choose the order\nin which you would like to go.')
        self.frame_2_label.grid()

        self.chosen_city = {}
        self.city_combobox = {}
        self.ordered_city_list = []
        for city in self.selected_cities:
            self.city_label = Label(self.frame_2, text='City #' + str((self.selected_cities.index(city) + 1)) + ': ')
            self.city_label.grid(sticky=W)
            self.chosen_city[city] = BooleanVar()
            self.city_combobox[city] = ttk.Combobox(self.frame_2, values=self.selected_cities,
                                                    textvariable=self.chosen_city[city], width=25, state='readonly')
            self.city_combobox[city].grid(sticky=W)
            self.city_combobox[city].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.ordered_city_list.append(self.city_combobox[city].get()))

        continue2_button = Button(self.frame_2, text='Next', command=self.frame_2.destroy)
        continue2_button.grid(sticky=N)      

    def choose_cities(self):
        self.selected_cities = []
        for city in self.cities:
            if self.selected[city].get():
                self.selected_cities.append(city)
                self.canvas.create_oval((self.cities[city][0] - 8), (self.cities[city][1] - 8),
                                        (self.cities[city][0] + 8), (self.cities[city][1] + 8), fill='orange')
                if city == 'Traverse City' or city == 'Detroit':
                    self.canvas.create_text((self.cities[city][0] + 3), (self.cities[city][1] + 3), text=city, anchor=NW, fill='orange')
                else:
                    self.canvas.create_text((self.cities[city][0] - 3), (self.cities[city][1] - 3), text=city, anchor=SE, fill='orange')
```

Comment: This isn't a 1-to-1 solution for what you are doing, but it demonstrates how user input values are saved even as new questions are asked, with final results (in my case a % of correct answers, and in your case a route for locations) being displayed at the end. perhaps it'll help - https://nerdi.org/programming/python/python-multiple-choice/ - it basically just goes over how a user can select from multiple answers (or obviously input custom values) and then how that's stored over time